# How to run selenium IDE on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run selenium IDE on chrome. for that i have to write following cmd command. As it is shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cM39_SVCheA)

`E:\Automation\Selenium>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar chromedriver.exe`

But it gives me the error like below :

```
Exception in thread “main” com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter ‘chromedriver.exe’ but no main parameter was defined 

at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.getMainParameter(JCommander.java:914) 
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:759) 
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282) 
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265) 
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.(JCommander.java:210) 
at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:227) 
at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:155) 
at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:75)
```

Please let me know if am doing anything wrong in the above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it like this

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar
```